# React + Redux Do something after component update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux

I'm having some trouble with React and Redux. Well I know how to fix it but I'm not sure if it's the best solution. I'm creating a basic chat application and whenever I add a message the box should scroll to the bottom.

So what I'm basically asking is there a way to run a function after a redux update has updated the components ? I know I should be able to catch this in the `componentDidUpdate` but I feel there is a better solution. And I want to keep my components as pure functions.

I've tried calling it from `mapStateToProps`but that is before the actual components are updated.

Right now I've got it working with [react-functional](https://github.com/davidmarkclements/react-functional). But that makes the component not so pure anymore.

ChatBox.js

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import functional from 'react-functional';

import Message from './Message';

const MessageBox =  ({messages}) => (
  <section className='chatbox'>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName='bubble' transitionEnterTimeout={700} transitionLeaveTimeout={700}>
      {messages.map(message =>
        <Message
          key={message.id}
          {...message}
        />
      )}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </section>
);

const options = {
  componentDidUpdate: () => {
    const chatbox = document.querySelector(`.chatbox`);
    if (chatbox) {
      const scroll = chatbox.scrollHeight - chatbox.clientHeight;
      document.querySelector(`.chatbox`).scrollTop = scroll;
    }
  }
};

MessageBox.propTypes = {
  messages: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    image: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }).isRequired).isRequired
};


export default functional(MessageBox, options);
```

Comment: Seems like in your attempts to create pure components, you're jumping through unnecessary hoops to include a side effect that is necessary in your application. Why not wrap your functional components in a regular one where you can use the out-of-the-box life cycle methods available to you (rather than use a third party library)

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering if there was any way to do it in this way. Like I said I know I can just use a class. But I was mostly curious if there was a way to not do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want requires the use of lifecycle methods, I see no other way of doing that.
Personally, I highly recommend you to follow the conventions.
It will allow any other developer to easily understand your code.